# How to access List of WeakReference in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have question about WeakReference. I've list of MyClass.

```
List<WeakReference<MyClass>> myClass= new ArrayList<WeakReference<MyClass>>();    
WeakReference<List<WeakReference<MyClass>>> weakList = new WeakReference<List<WeakReference<MyClass>>>(myClass);
```

I'm passing this list (myClass) to JSP. Now I want to access object of MyClass from the list in JSP using

```
<c:forEach
```

loop. Could you please suggest me the way.

Thank you

Comment: Transform that list into a `List<MyClass>` in your controller, and pass that list to the JSP.

Comment: Can't I access as it is? Because we are using heavy collections and might have chance of insufficient memory exceptions

Comment: If you don't have enough memory to create an ArrayList of things to display in the JSP, then there is a good chance you don't have enough memory to execute the JSP in the first place. Remember that the ArrayList would simply store references to objects that **already** exist in the list of weak references. And ithe list should be short, since it's supposed to contain elements to display in a HTML page. Surely you don't want to display a list of millions of elements in a HTML page. The view shouldn't have to deal with weak references.